# How to count objects having the same 2 parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, count

I am trying to prepare a dataset by using the following;

```
   distance  Time
0         9     0
1         7     0
2        22     0
3        30     0
4        15     0
5         7     0
6        25     0
7         9     0
8         9     0
```

max value of time is 1800 and distance is 56. The targeted dataset will contain count of the same parameters. For instance;

```
 distance   Time   Count
0    0       0        x
1    1       0        y
2    2       0        z
.    .       .        .
k    56     1800      t
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Yes it is. I need to count the number of inputs having the same distance and time parameters.

Comment: I don't know if I got it right but you could use a map (a data structure based on pairs of keys and values): your key would be the couple time/distance and your value the count number. Maps are accessible by key int this way: map(key) == value, so by scanning the entire dataset, each time you find a couple dist/time, you perform map([dist, time]) += 1 incrementing its value by one. [dist, time] could be a simple struct, array or whatever you prefer. This is language agnostic, you should check how to implement a map in python.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are not interested in "zero results", just
group by both columns and compute *size* for each group:

```
df.groupby(['distance', 'Time']).size()
```

If you want to have *distance* and *Time* back as "normal" columns, call *reset_index()*.

Comment: ahh, i was literally thinking the count should be x,y,z etc.. need a coffee :D